# combine two time ranges in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

a time series data in mongodb as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d894"), "code" : "ZL0KOP", "time" : NumberLong("1420128024000"),"direction" : "10", "siteId" : "0000"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d895"), "code" : "AQ0ZSQ", "time" : NumberLong("1420128025000"),"direction" : "10", "siteId" : "0000"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d896"), "code" : "AQ0ZSQ", "time" : NumberLong("1420128003000"),"direction" : "10", "siteId" : "0000"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d897"), "code" : "ZL0KOP", "time" : NumberLong("1420041724000"),"direction" : "10", "siteId" : "0000"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d89e"), "code" : "YBUHCW", "time" : NumberLong("1420041732000"),"direction" : "10", "siteId" : "0002"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d8a1"), "code" : "U48AIW", "time" : NumberLong("1420041729000"),"direction" : "10", "siteId" : "0002"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d8a0"), "code" : "OJ3A06", "time" : NumberLong("1420300927000"),"direction" : "10", "siteId" : "0000"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d89d"), "code" : "AQ0ZSQ", "time" : NumberLong("1420300885000"),"direction" : "10", "siteId" : "0003"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d8a2"), "code" : "ZLV05H", "time" : NumberLong("1420300922000"),"direction" : "10", "siteId" : "0001"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d8a3"), "code" : "AQ0ZSQ", "time" : NumberLong("1420300928000"),"direction" : "10", "siteId" : "0000"}
```

The codes that match two or more conditions need to be filtered out.
For example:

```
condition1: 1420128000000 < time < 1420128030000,siteId == 0000
condition2: 1420300880000 < time < 1420300890000,siteId == 0003
```

The only code that matchs all the conditions above should be:

{"code" : "AQ0ZSQ"}

I use the following query:

```
db.codes.find({$and:[{'time': {'$gt': 1420128000000,'$lt': 1420128030000}, 'siteId': "0000"},{'time': {'$gt': 1420300880000,'$lt': 1420300890000}},{'siteId':'0003'}]})
```

No result found and the explain show that:

```
 "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$and" : [
                            {
                                    "time" : {
                                            "$lt" : 1421856012000
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : {
                                            "$lt" : 1420560012000
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "siteId" : {
                                            "$eq" : "0000"
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "siteId" : {
                                            "$eq" : "0000"
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : {
                                            "$gt" : 1421722392000
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "time" : {
                                            "$gt" : 1420426392000
                                    }
                            }
                    ]
            },
```

which obviously not correct.
So how can I find the correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) here and not [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/). An "AND" would be impossible because no record has both "0000" and "0003" for the siteId. So you mean "either" which means "OR":

```js
db.codes.find({
    "$or": [
        { 
            "time": { "$gt": 1420128000000, "$lt": 1420128030000 },
            "siteId": "0000"
        },
        {
            "time": { "$gt": 1420300880000, "$lt": 1420300890000 },
            "siteId": "0003"
        }
    ]
})
```

Which gives you the results with just the key you expect:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d895"),
    "code" : "AQ0ZSQ",
    "time" : NumberLong("1420128025000"), 
    "direction" : "10", 
    "siteId" : "0000"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d896"), 
    "code" : "AQ0ZSQ", 
    "time" : NumberLong("1420128003000"), 
    "direction" : "10",
    "siteId" : "0000" 
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d89d"),
    "code" : "AQ0ZSQ",
    "time" : NumberLong("1420300885000"), 
    "direction" : "10",
    "siteId" : "0003"
 }
```

---

### Reductive logic in a nutshell

Since there seems to be a misunderstanding in the terms here I will try to explain a simply as possible. Let us consider these basic documents:

```js
{ "a": 1, "b": true },
{ "a": 2, "b": false },
{ "a": 3, "b": true },
{ "a": 4, "b": false },
{ "a": 5, "b": true },
{ "a": 6, "b": true }
```

Now while first focussing on a single range match then the following will produce results:

```js
db.collection.find({ "a": { "$gt": 1, "$lt": 6 } })
```

Since four of the six documents here will contain a value of "a" that falls between the specified range.

Now you can also use "two" ranges here within an `$and` condition as follows:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$and": [
        { "a": { "$gt": 1, "$lt": 6 } },
        { "a": { "$gt": 2, "$lt": 5 } }
    ]
})
```

Again now both documents with "a" for 3 and 4 will match "both" conditions of course discarding values of 2 and 5 because the second condition was not met.

The **Reductive** point here is the expression can actually be simplified to just the range that has the "greater" minimum value and the "lesser" maximum value:

```js
db.collection.find({ "a": { "$gt": 2, "$lt": 5 } })
```

Which is the same result from above.

Rather than "contained" logic the same applies to "intersections" of conditions, so the following:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$and": [
        { "a": { "$gt": 1, "$lt": 4 } },
        { "a": { "$gt": 2, "$lt": 6 } }
    ]
})
```

Then reduces down to this basic statement by the same "minimum" and "maximum" rules:

```js
db.collection.find({ "a": { "$gt": 2, "$lt": 4 } })
```

Both return just document 3 as is covered by basic reduction.

However where there is **no overlap** in the ranges then nothing will match:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$and": [
        { "a": { "$gt": 1, "$lt": 3 } },
        { "a": { "$gt": 2, "$lt": 6 } }
    ]
})
```

No document meets those conditions since 3,4,5 meet the second statement but all of 3,4,5 were excluded by the first statement. Again this just "reduces" down to this:

```js
db.collection.find({ "a": { "$gt": 2, "$lt": 3 } })
```

Where there is clearly no match for a number between 2 and 3 in this collection.

---

Looking now at the second "b" property alone you can do this:

```js
db.collection.find({ "b": true })
```

Which only returns results for `true` as expected. But if you tried this:

```js
db.collection.find({
   "$and": [
       { "b": true },
       { "b": false } 
   ]
})
```

Then there is "no match possible" because no single document contains both `true` **and** `false` for "b" *at the same time*. Only an `$or` condition can match documents testing "either" of those values:

```js
db.collection.find({
   "$or": [
       { "b": true },
       { "b": false } 
   ]
})
```

So of course all documents in the sample because nothing contains another possible value for "b" that was not mentioned in the conditions.

A shorter operator for that is the `$in` operator, which can test an "or" on the same field without fully declaring it, as in:

```js
db.collection.find({ "b": { "$in": [true,false] } })
```

---

Now if you "combine" the principles, how the second exaple with `$and` cannot work with a range combination should be clear:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$and": [
        { "a": { "$gt": 1, "$lt": 4 }, "b": true },
        { "a": { "$gt": 2, "$lt": 6 }, "b": false }
    ]
})
```

So while the "range" satified document for "a" equal to 3 that document does not have "both" `true` and `false` values. It's "only" value is `true` so no conditions are met an no document matches.

In order to match the document with "a" 3 then the logic would be written in "redcued" form like so:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "a": { "$gt": 2, "$lt": 4 },
    "b": { "$in": [true,false] }
})
```

In that case then document "a" equal to 3 is the match because the reduced range was found as well as the test for "b" beign equal to one of the values for `true/false`.

And of course finally to consider "b" as an "or" condition you would do:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$or": [
        { "a": { "$gt": 2, "$lt": 4 } },
        { "b": { "$in": [true,false] } }
    ]
})
```

Which of course matches "everything" in the sample as the first "range" matched document "a" equal to 3 but **all documents** contain values of "b" that are either `true/false`.

---

That is how this all pans out. There is a basic reductive rule than can be applied for a range as is described earlier and it is just *not possible* for a "singular" value to have *more than one* value at a time.

This is basic logic and not theoritical physics, so [Schrödinger's cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger's_cat) does not apply here :)

Comment: By using $or, the query selects the documents in the collection that match at least one condition. But what I need is documents that match all conditions. I edited my question and add a new document to the top of the list

Comment: @bresai And the query as shown here will match the document that you added as well. `$or` is correct here. The conditions inside each "or" argument are "and" conditions. Saying "and" on the outer does not make any sense because no document can have siteId "0000" **and** "0003". That's an impossible match. But I already said that. If you expect something else then your intent is still unclear.

Comment: There may be some misunderstanding between us. I tried your code, and the result contains 4 documents. But the document
    { "_id" : ObjectId("558912b845cea070a982d894"), "code" : "ZL0KOP", "time" : NumberLong("1420128024000"), "direction" : "10", "siteId" : "0000" } should not be include, since it only match one of the two conditions.

Comment: @bresai There sure seems to be a misunderstanding here somewhere. The document you added falls within the two timestamp values provided and matches siteId "0000". So 1420128024000 is less than  1420128030000 and is greater than 1420128000000 as well so that also matches and it should be included. What else you are asking here who knows because you are not explaining clearly. No document can have more than one timestamp or siteId value asking for a match on "both" timestamp in this range and timestamp in that range as well as this siteId and that one as well is impossible logic.

Comment: @bresai Since you seem to be struggling with defining the logic for what you want and defining an example with explained logic for why only certain results should match, then consider the "little" addendum added here to explain logic patterns and exclusions.

Comment: Thanks for your patient, I think the title is really misleading. So I marked this one as solved and posted another question. Hope you can take look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095328/find-the-message-that-appeared-in-multi-time-ranges-for-mongodb-time-series-data